# « Cinq ans de mariage et puis s'en va » : Comment utilise-t-on cette expression ?

Tags: sens, usage

> Cinq ans de mariage **et puis s'en va**.
>
> Deux petites années **et puis s'en va**.

Je me demande si cette expression insiste sur la rapidité avec laquelle une certaine période de temps s'écoule en un clin d'œil?

Answer (score 2):

The expression comes from a well known nursery rhyme:

*[ainsi font, font, font, les petites marionnettes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ainsi_font).*

The person singing is moving his hands simulating the puppets and when the following verse ends:

> *Trois p'tits tours et puis s'en vont*

he hides his hands under is back and the baby laughs out loud.

In your examples, the metaphor is : after the show, a puppet disappears, i.e. after five years of marriage, one of the spouses is suddenly leaving.

Comment: So in the 2nd case, after two years, someone disappears from somewhere? Also, does it have nothing to do with the idea of "how fast time passes"?

Comment: 1. very likely. 2. it is generally unrelated to how fast time passes outside the suddenness of the leave.

Comment: I agree with comment 2 from jiliagre: it rather stresses that the spouse came out of nowhere, was married for a short period of time, and then left suddenly for good. Like the puppets in the nursery rhyme (you have to hide the puppets switfly behind your back along with the line *et puis s'en vont*), the idea is that someone/something appears unexpectedly, is very visible/very active for a while, and then disappears as quickly as it appeared.

Comment: If more than one person are disappearing, then does the plural apply? "et puis s'en **vont**" Also to @Greg

Comment: The plural is used in that case, like with the two puppets.

Comment: So is it like: "Deux petites années et puis (**quelqu'un**) s'en va."?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, you don't have to mention the subject, to use the same "poetic" form as in the rhyme. Another example for the usage: I would use it for instance in this situation: imagine you work in a company, you have a new boss hired from outside, he stays for 2 years, and then leaves from one day to the other and you never hear about him again. Then it would be fit to say "deux petites années et puis s'en va".

Comment: Yes, the subject is implicit and no pronoun is used because the sentence is technically truncated. The rhyme translates to something like "they do that way, the little puppets, they do that way, three little swirls and then they go away"